# There is no row position at zero (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Well I just want to know the solution for having no row position at zero since I tried the solution from a research but does not work.

```
 Private Sub Menu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TimerDate.Start()
    connMainMenu.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\BANKDetails.accdb"
    connMainMenu.Open()
    AdapatMainMenu1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from BANKreg where FirstName= '" + WelcomeTexttxt.Text + "'", connMainMenu)
    DsetMainMenu1 = New DataSet
    AdapatMainMenu1.Fill(DsetMainMenu1)

    WelcomeTexttxt.Text = "Welcome " & DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString()

    connMainMenu.Close()
```

The problem now is even I used the If condition still draws an error. The primary key I've put is FIrstName (not ID since I removed it through MS ACCESS during the making of the database from scratch)

Comment: You can check with [Vignesh Kumar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2118383/vignesh-kumar) answer

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no record in your Dataset.
So you need to check before going to handle like this

```
If DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso DsetMainMenu1.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso DsetMainMenu1 IsNot Nothing Then
   WelcomeTexttxt.Text = "Welcome " & DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString()
End If
```

And one more thing is better to use ColumnName instead of ColumnIndex

```
If DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso DsetMainMenu1.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso DsetMainMenu1 IsNot Nothing Then
   WelcomeTexttxt.Text = "Welcome " & DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ColumnName").ToString()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If catching the error is your problem, try this:

```
If DsetMainMenu1.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    If DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        WelcomeTexttxt.Text = "Welcome " & DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString()
    End If
End If
```

Check first if there are tables, then if there's any, check the `0` index table for rows

As for getting the exact column value, something like this (replace the `nameOfAccount` with your right column of choice):

```
WelcomeTexttxt.Text = "Welcome " & DsetMainMenu1.Tables(0).Rows(0)("nameOfAccount").ToString()
```

Comment: It works but why it didn't show the corresponding code in the textbox when a specific account was entered. "Welcome: (Name of the account)"

Comment: @jamescv31 May i know the code you tried for **"Welcome: (Name of the account)"**

Comment: Its strange because the program I'm making from a scratch is based on "source code" that I've found however still weird why doesn't recognized the name.

Comment: Is there a problem from the code for DataSet? Because the Database program I'm using is DATABASE.NET from (fishcodelib.com)

Comment: How to check if the table in the dataset has a record? Because there nothing wrong on the Accdb file of MS Access.